# How do I get the "context" value of a Bundle in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to iterate the list of files that have been added to a specific bundle.

For instance, if I have a bundle that was created like this:

```
'_App_Start.vbhtml:
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles)

'BundleConfig.vb:
Imports System.Web.Optimization
Public Class BundleConfig        
Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(ByRef bundles As BundleCollection)
   bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/example").Include( 
      "~/Scripts/file1.js", 
      "~/Scripts/file2.js"
   ))
End Sub
End Class
```

From other *.vbhtml files in the project, I want to be able to iterate a bundle, "~/bundles/example" in this example, in order to obtain the list of files, "~/Scripts/file1.js" and "~/Scripts/file2.js", in this example.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
Dim myBundle As System.Web.Optimization.Bundle
myBundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/bundles/example")

'== Stuck Here:
Dim myContext As BundleContext
myContext = "** Pleae Help **"

Dim myIEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of BundleFile)
myIEnumerable = myBundle.EnumerateFiles(myContext)
```

Looking at the docs for the Bundle.EnumerateFiles method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundle.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) I see that the first argument is the "BundleContext".

This is where I **was** stuck!
How or where do I get the BundleContext value to pass to the EnumerateFiles method?

**Edit - Complete working example that uses the code provided in Tetsuya's answer**

```
Dim myBundle As System.Web.Optimization.Bundle
myBundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/bundles/example")

Dim currentContext As HttpContext = httpContext.Current

Dim httpCtxt As HttpContextWrapper
httpCtxt = New HttpContextWrapper(currentContext)

Dim myContext As BundleContext
myContext = New BundleContext(httpCtxt, BundleTable.Bundles, "~/bundles/example")

Dim myIEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of BundleFile)
myIEnumerable = myBundle.EnumerateFiles(myContext)

Dim filepath As String
For Each bundlefile In myIEnumerable.ToArray
    filepath = bundlefile.IncludedVirtualPath
    ' do stuff ..
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundlecontext.bundlecontext(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), `BundleContext` is a class which its constructor accepts 3 arguments as shown below:

```
Public Class BundleContext
    Public Sub New (context As HttpContextBase, collection As BundleCollection, bundleVirtualPath As String)
End Class
```

Hence, you need to pass `HttpContext`, `BundleTable.Bundles` (this is default `BundleCollection`, change to custom bundle collection if you have any) and bundle virtual path to create a `BundleContext` instance like this example:

```
Dim currentContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

Dim contextWrapper As HttpContextWrapper
contextWrapper = New HttpContextWrapper(currentContext)

Dim myContext As BundleContext
myContext = New BundleContext(contextWrapper, BundleTable.Bundles, "~/bundles/example")
```

Comment: Visual Studio Smart Sense got confused when using httpContext as a variable name so I had to rename that variable and then it worked.  Thank you!